# How to cast a swift array of tuples to NSMutableArray?

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, nsmutablearray

I have swift array of tuples `[(String, String)]` and would like to cast this array to NSMutableArray. I have tried this and it is not working:

```
let myNSMUtableArray = swiftArrayOfTuples as! AnyObject as! NSMutableArray
```

Comment: you can't. change the tuple for a 2D array `[[String]]` and save it as `[AnyObject]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since swift types like `Tuple` or `Struct` have no equivalent in Objective-C they can not be cast to or referenced as `AnyObject` which `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` constrain their element types to.

The next best thing if you must return an NSMutableArray from a swift Array of tuples might be returning an Array of 2 element Arrays:

```
let itemsTuple = [("Pheonix Down", "Potion"), ("Elixer", "Turbo Ether")]
let itemsArray = itemsTuple.map { [$0.0, $0.1] }
let mutableItems = NSMutableArray(array: itemsArray)
```

Comment: `NSMutableArray(array: itemsArray)` this was the trick

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with what you are trying to do:

- Swift array can be cast to `NSArray`, but it cannot be cast to `NSMutableArray` without constructing a copy
- Swift tuples have no Cocoa counterpart, so you cannot cast them or Swift collections containing them to Cocoa types.

Here is how you construct `NSMutableArray` from a Swift array of `String` objects:

```
var arr = ["a"]
arr.append("b")
let mutable = (arr as AnyObject as! NSArray).mutableCopy()
mutable.addObject("c")
print(mutable)
```