# Why is NSArray mutable when used from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsarray

I have an objective-c header with the following property

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSArray<CustomObject *> *customObjects;
```

If I create a swift extension of that class I can now remove objects from the NSArray:

```
self.customObjects?.remove(at: 0)
```

Also if I do

```
print(type(of: self.customObjects))
```

I get:

```
Array<CustomObject>
```

Aren't NSArrays immutable ? Does Swift create a shallow copy whenever we edit it?

Comment: NSArray's are not mutable. There is mutable version of it called NSMutableArray.

Comment: That's because you don't use it as `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast a swift array of tuples to NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611440/how-to-cast-a-swift-array-of-tuples-to-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 1):

Your property is (implicitly) declared `readwrite` in ObjC. This means you can change the property writing a new `NSArray` instance that replaces the old (in which case the new instance's constants might be derived by first reading the other `NSArray` instance that's the existing value of the property):

```
NSArray *currentObjects = self.customObjects;
// one of many ways to derive one immutable array from another:
NSArray *newArray = [currentObjects subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, currentObjects.count - 1)];
self.customObjects = newArray;
```

In Swift, your property comes across as a `Swift.Array` (that is, the `Array` type from the Swift standard library), which is a value type. Every assignment semantically creates a copy. (The expensive work of performing the copy can be deferred, using a "copy on write" pattern. Arrays of reference types, like objects, copy references instead of storage, so it's essentially a "shallow copy".)

Mutating operations do this, too:

```
let currentObjects1 = self.customObjects
currentObjects1.remove(0) // compile error
// currentObjects1 is a `let` constant so you can't mutate it

var currentObjects = self.customObjects
currentObjects.remove(0) // ok

print(self.customObjects.count - currentObjects.count) 
// this is 1, because currentObjects is a copy of customObjects
// we mutated the former but not the latter so their count is different

self.customObjects = currentObjects
// now we've replaced the original with the mutated copy just as in the ObjC example
```

When you have a readwrite property in Swift, and the type of that property is a value type like `Array` (or is an ObjC type that's bridged to a value type, like `NSArray`), you can use mutating methods directly on the property. That's because calling a mutating method is semantically equivalent to reading (and copying) the existing value, mutating the copy, and then writing back the changed copy.

```
// all equivalent
self.customObjects.remove(0)
self.customObjects = self.customObjects.dropFirst(1)
var objects = self.customObjects; objects.remove(0); self.customObjects = objects
```

---

BTW: If you're designing the API for the ObjC class in question here, you might consider making your `customObjects` property nonnull — unless there's a meaningful semantic difference between an empty array and a missing array, your Swift clients will find it cumbersome needing to distinguish the two.

Comment: You've accurately described what the current Swift compiler does, but clearly removing the immutability isn't the only choice that could have been made here. Do you have a reference for this being the *defined* behaviour? (Yes, I know there is no formal semantics for Swift but its nice to some indication behaviour like this isn't just an artifact of the current compiler.)